# How do I level epic dragons past level 10?

Tags: dragonvale

I have been able to level up half my elemental dragons past level 10. I don't know how to level my epic dragons past level 10, though.

Comment: Are Rare dragons any different then elemental ones?  If not, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60950/how-do-i-level-my-dragons-past-level-10.

Comment: There are many dragons which do not map to any elements, and these are rare. I do not know if some dragons (such as Panlong dragons or opposite dragons) might be called "rare" (they are less frequent to breed and are affected by bonuses to breeding "rare" dragons, IIRC) which are affected by shrines. Still, the dragons in the 'rare' category when selecting to filter are separate and aren't covered in the linked question.

Comment: @fbueckert Sorry if my previous explanation was too wordy. While some dragons which are elemental (thus covered by the previous question) might be considered "rare", there are other dragons which are explicitly "rare" which are not covered by the other question. This question asks about those, and DKnight's answer covers it.

Comment: The correct terminology is "Epic" and "Gemstone". These are the "rare" dragons you are referring to which can't level past 10. Some dragons are also "Limited", ie available for a limited time. Limited Dragons may be of any kind (Gemstone, Epic, Common).

Comment: @EBongo Oh, good, somebody who does play Dragonvale.  I tried to clarify the question, but I'm not sure if I managed it.  If I broke it, feel free to fix it.

Comment: Non-elemental seems the best description. Epic and Gemstone fall under a single tab in-game. Rare equally describes Epic, Gemstone, Limited, and even Opposite dragons.

Answer (score 3):

You can't at this point, to level past 10 it has to be elemental.

If that were to change, and use the current system of shrines, you will be able to find details here:

http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Shrines

Answer (score 2):

If you participated in, and perfected, the Star Fall event, you received a special reward building that raises the level limit on Epic dragons to level 15. It did not effect Gemstone dragons, so their limit remains level 10 regardless.

Prior to this reward building, there was no way to raise the level limit of Epic dragons from the max level of 10.