# How do I level up special dragons past level 10?

Tags: dragonvale

I have many special dragons and I can't figure out how to level them past ten.

Comment: Dupe of either: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/93203/how-do-i-level-non-elemental-dragons-past-level-10, or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60950/how-do-i-level-my-dragons-past-level-10, but I don't know which, because I don't know what special dragons are being referred to.

Answer (score 0):

To raise Epic dragons to level 15, you need to have completed the Star Fall event completely. For perfecting the event, players were rewarded with a special building that raised Epic dragons max level to level 15.

If you did not participate in the Star Fall event, or if you did not perfect it during the event, then your Epic dragons are still limited to level 10.

Gemstone dragons max level was not affected by the Star Fall event reward, because of this their max level is still level 10.